# Unable to deserialize contract after changing route registration

Tags: asp.net, wcf, serialization, wcf-web-api

I have an existing WCF Web API app that is registering routes using the following pattern:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("MyService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MyServiceImplementation)));
```

I recently updated to Preview 6.  I also updated the registration pattern in Global.asax to use the enhancements extension:

```
routes.SetDefaultHttpConfiguration(new MyServiceConfiguration());
routes.MapServiceRoute<MyServiceImplementation>("MyService");
```

I also have a contract that I am posting to a method in a request.

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/MyOperation", Method = "POST")]
Contact MyOperation(Contact contact);
```

...

```
[DataContract( Name = "Contact" )]
public class Contact : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    [StringLength(50)]
    [StringNotEmpty]
    [DataMember(Name = "FirstName", Order = 1)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "LastName", Order = 1)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    //[StringLength(50)]
    //[DataMember(Name = "Location", Order = 1)]
    //public String Location { get; set; }

    public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData { get; set; }
}
```

The issue I am getting is that when I post a previously acceptable contract, such as:

```
<Contact xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://myservice/schema">
   <FirstName>John</FirstName>
   <LastName>Smith</LastName>
   <Location i:nil="true" />
</Contact>
```

I get the following exception:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the
>   service
>   help page for constructing valid requests to the service. The
>   exception message is 'The service operation 'MyOperation' expected a
>   value assignable to type 'Contact' for input parameter 'contact' but
>   received a value of type 'HttpRequestMessage`1'.'. See server logs for
>   more details.

I found that if I remove the ***xmlns="http://myservice/schema"*** from my request, the service accepts the request.  I have existing api clients that will be making calls to the new service with this present, so I have to make sure these messages are accepted.

I understand that the WCF Web Api Enhancements (extension method) I am using uses different classes under the hood; but I am a little ignorant at the moment as to why one would be able to deserialize and the other would not.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WCF Web API doesn use the DataContact serializer but the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) so you will need to use those attributed to decorate your Contract class. Try adding the XmlRootAttribute with a Namespace to the Contract class.

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://myservice/schema")]
public class Contact 
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: That did it!  So, I had read (http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2011/05/15/using-datacontracts-with-wcf-web-api/) that you could tag your contract with the [DataContractFormat] attribute to get it to use the DataContractSerializer.  Any idea why that would not work?

Comment: They have been making a lot of braking changes changes between versions. Using the element focused DataContractSerializer really doesn't make sense with a REST service. They still use the JSONDataContractSerializer though.